# How to create a function that will return a length (n) with multiples of (x)?

Tags: javascript

```
function countBy(x, n) {

    var z = [];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        z.push(z[i] + x);
   }

    return z;

}
```

The results I'm getting from the test code Test.assertSimilar(countBy(1,5), [1,2,3,4,5]) are [null,null,null,null,null]. I assume this is because the z array is initially empty. I've searched for some help on this problem but I can't seem to find any. Thank you!

Comment: You need more details. With `Test.assertSimilar(actual, expected)`, we're checking that the `actual` value equals (===) the `expected` value. So are you _expecting_ `countBy(x,n)` to perform it's first multiple of `x` by 0 or by 1? The difference is that the resulting array would be `[0,1,2,3,4]` instead of `[1,2,3,4,5]`; that later is what you were using to compare. Or maybe you were expecting Test.assertSimilar to return false? Zero is a multiple of all numbers so I'd personally be shooting to start my first multiplication off with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// z is the variable you're building. `z[i]` does not exist yet.
z.push(z[i] + x);

// You want this..
z.push(i*x);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9h911x28/

also, matter of preference, but you probably also want to start `i` out as `1` instead of `0`.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

Comment: Preference doesn't override _good programming practice_, which is that we start at `i=0` because this is the first index element of arrays in almost all programming languages. So, even though you may start _your_ array at index 1, you have an unused and wasted index at 0. Additionally, any programmer you work with is going to be blindsided by this move when they go to access your arrays.

Comment: @8protons I agree with you, but in this case the array would be 0 indexed as it's not keyed by `i`, instead it has a value of `i * x`, so starting a loop at 1 makes sense when you won't want to multiply by 0.

Comment: So then is your suggestion from _a matter of preference_ or _a matter or practicality_ with regards to your solution?

Comment: @8protons just a note, it's not my solution. Just commenting on the code and your comment.

Comment: @8protons - it's a matter of preference because it depends if you want the program to give 0 as the first number or 1 as the first number. We're using Array.prototype.push to build the array so your statement about arrays and good practice is moot. The array will always start at zero.

Comment: @8protons `Test.assertSimilar` has nothing to do with the fact that `countBy()` is incorrect. It's misleading that he added that to the question, but that has nothing to do with my answer. If you want to downvote the answer go ahead, don't downvote me for answering..

Comment: @Pamblam steady now, there is a point to be taken away from this without the need for an emotional response. You have to consider that anyone may downvote even the best answers to questions for not considering a possibility. That is, in essence the beauty of peer reviewed code, public or not.

Comment: @Pamblam Thanks for the quick response. I was totally failing to see (i*x) for some reason. I guess that's why I'm doing practice problems though! I also needed to set i=1 instead of i=0 because, of course, the array would start at 0. P.S. What's with the downvotes?

Comment: @wahoowa - Glad I could be helpful. SO, like any online community has a lot of trolls who downvote for no reason. Your question was valid and I gave you an upvote. If this answered your question please hit the check mark by the answer :). Godspeed..